# Can I replace this RF amplifier (25A250, Amplifier Research) with a narrow-band amplifier to generate a 200 kHz signal?

Tags: amplifier, ultrasound, power-amplifier

I am working in an ultrasound lab that currently uses an RF amplifier (25A250, Amplifier Research) to generate a 200 kHz pulsed signal. The amplifier is receiving a signal from the AFG3022B Tektronix signal generator and powering two single-element piezo transducers (MCUSD19A200B11RS, Farnell).
We only need an amplifier that generates a 200 kHz signal (while varying other parameters), is it possible to replace the amplifier with a narrow-band equivalent? e.g. a Mono 200W Discrete Power Amplifier -  WSAH8060

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

An amplifer doesn't generally *generate* a signal, it *amplifies* a signal. Using correct terminology matters when asking a question.

You signal generator is generating the 200 kHz signal, the amplifier increases the level of the signal. As long as the amplifier can handle the entire bandwidth of the signal, and the input and outputs are specified to handle the impedances and levels involved it should work.

Where you might run into trouble going to a narrower bandwidth is with the harmonics of your signal. A sine wave will have a single frequency, in your case 200 kHz. A square wave will have many harmonics (multiples) of that frequency, if the amplifier can't handle or reproduce those harmonics your signal will be distorted. At the extreme, putting a square wave through a very narrow bandwidth will basically turn it into a sine wave. Other waveforms will have more or less harmonics, but if your amplifier starts to reduce the signal level anywhere below the second harmonic, 400 kHz in your case, you will lose part of your signal for anything but a sine wave.